# Django PayPal & Additional Options

Tags: django, django-paypal

I'm using [Django PayPal](http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal). PayPal has a [list of options](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) you can pass on your button. I'm trying to add some of these to my `paypal_dict`

```
paypal_dict = {
    # ...

    # preopulate paypal checkout page
    "email": invoice.user.email,
    "first_name": invoice.user.first_name,
    "last_name": invoice.user.last_name,
    "address1": invoice.user.address.street,
    "city": invoice.user.address.city,
    "country": invoice.user.address.get_country_display,
    "address_country_code": invoice.user.address.country
}

form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
```

But when I inspect the form, these fields are never added. How can I get them to be added?

Comment: Hi Mark - just a quick heads-up, the jonboxall fork isn't the most up to date Django-Paypal - the dcramer one is way ahead, and the main fork to track. See http://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal/network

Comment: Ah.. I knew there were two main forks, but I couldn't remember which was newer. Whichever turned up first in Google I assumed was the better one :p Anyway.. I'll have to check to see which one I'm actually using, but.... I think this is still an issue in dcramer's version, isn't it?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, as I haven't used django-paypal, but... In documentation you linked to in your question there is no `email` variable, just `receiver_email` and `payer_email`. The same for some other options you listed...

Comment: @Tomek: Yes... but PayPal itself supports a lot more options than that.

Comment: @Mark: You wrote: "PayPal has a list of options[...] I'm trying to add some of these[...]" and gave a link to PayPal's API documentation. Then you used some option not documented in linked documentation. Then you ask us, why they don't work. So I ask you: **"Why do you think they should work?"**

Comment: I didn't ask why they don't work. I realize they're obviously not implemented. I asked *how can* I get them to be added; i.e., a workaround. I *tried* it this way, because I assumed there would be a 1:1 mapping; that each item in the dict would simply get converted into an input option. Would have been nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked it in:

```
def __init__(self, button_type="buy", extra_options={}, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PayPalPaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.extra_options = extra_options
    self.button_type = button_type

def render(self):
    extra_fields = u''.join(['<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />' % (escape(name), escape(value)) for name, value in self.extra_options.iteritems()])          
    return mark_safe(u"""<form action="%s" method="post">
%s
%s
<input type="image" src="%s" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>""" % (POSTBACK_ENDPOINT, self.as_p(), extra_fields, self.get_image()))


def sandbox(self):
    extra_fields = u''.join(['<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />' % (escape(name), escape(value)) for name, value in self.extra_options.iteritems()])  
    return mark_safe(u"""<form action="%s" method="post">
%s
%s
<input type="image" src="%s" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>""" % (SANDBOX_POSTBACK_ENDPOINT, self.as_p(), extra_fields, self.get_image()))
```

Comment: why not contribute to django-paypal on github?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some additional fields:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: Updated url: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview

Answer (score 1):

I found much cleaner solution without modifying original code thanks to Python multiple inheritance.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from paypal.standard.widgets import ValueHiddenInput
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalEncryptedPaymentsForm


class PayPalAddressFormMixin(forms.Form):

    address1 = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    address2 = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    city = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    country = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    zip = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())

    email = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())


class PayPalEncryptedPaymentsAddressForm(PayPalEncryptedPaymentsForm, PayPalAddressFormMixin):
    pass
```

in views.py you can set initial values as usual

```
paypal_dict = {
    # ...

    # preopulate paypal checkout page
    "email": invoice.user.email,
    "first_name": invoice.user.first_name,
    "last_name": invoice.user.last_name,
    "address1": invoice.user.address.street,
    "city": invoice.user.address.city,
    "country": invoice.user.address.get_country_display,
    "address_country_code": invoice.user.address.country
}

form = PayPalEncryptedPaymentsAddressForm(initial=paypal_dict)
```